# SetText TextView in Android navigatorDrawer header

Tags: java, android, settext, navigation-drawer

How can i get textView from navigator drawer header? I was trying this:

```
 DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
 TextView text = (TextView) drawer.findViewById(R.id.textViewNames);
 text.setText("HELLO");
```

or

```
 NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
 try {
      View header = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.nav_header_profiler, null);
      navigationView.addHeaderView(header);
      TextView text = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.textViewNames);
      text.setText("HELLO");
 } catch (Exception e) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```

but nothing work. Always I got `NullPointerException. 
For some reason, this method simply appeal to the controls work:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
 @Override
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewNames);
      textView.setText(LoginActivity.FIRST_NAME + "\n" + LoginActivity.LAST_NAME);

      // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
      int id = item.getItemId();

      if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
           // Handle the camera action
      } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

      } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

      } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

      } else if (id == R.id.Find) {

      } else if (id == R.id.LogOut) {

      }

      DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
      drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
      return true;
 }
```

EDIT:
My logs:

> 02-07 08:00:04.307 8346-8346/com.example.krystian.beacon E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.krystian.beacon, PID: 8346
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.krystian.beacon/com.example.krystian.beacon.Witaj_Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.example.krystian.beacon.Witaj_Activity.onCreate(Witaj_Activity.java:45)
>       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
>       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: what, exactly, is the line
`Witaj_Activity.java:45`??

Comment: I use my function  replaceUserNames(ZalogujActivity.FIRST_NAME, ZalogujActivity.LAST_NAME);
In this function code: 
      TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewNames);
        text.setText("HELLO");

Answer (score 1):

Remove this attribute app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" the

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_activiy_drawer" />
```

and add in add dynamically in MainActivity

```
 NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        View headerView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main_activiy);
        ImageView user_iv = (ImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.user_iv);
        TextView fullName_tv = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.fullName_tv);
       TextView userEmail_tv = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.userEmail_tv);

        fullName_tv.setText("Your Full Name");
        userEmail_tv.setText("Your Email id");
```

**It is working in my case**